# How to change help text colour in password reset form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-crispy-forms

I have a password reset form (crispy form) in Django, I just changed background colour to black and text colour to white. But help text is remaining black as you can see:
[image: password change]

I tried to assign CSS style with white colour, I even tried to assign white colour with id and JavaScript and setProperty(), but text is still remaining black.

My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Password change{% endblock %}

{% block styling %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "styly_main.css" %}">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #192444;
        }
        .c2 {
            max-width: 280px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white !important;
            border: black solid 1px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 1rem;
            padding-bottom: 1.25rem;
            margin: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 350px;
            min-width: 340px;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock%}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden">
        
        {% include "includes/header_main.html" %}

        <div class="container c1">

            <div class="row gx-1">
                <div id="id1" class="col text-center pb-2 pt-3">
                    <H3>Password change</h3>
                    
                    <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="c2">
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i>  Submit</button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    
                    <p>
                        <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="a2">Back to Home.</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        {% include "includes/footer.html" %}

    </div>

{% endblock  %}

{% block script %}

<script>

const id1Elm = document.getElementById("id1");
id1Elm.style.setProperty('color', 'white', 'important');


</script>

{% endblock script %}
```

So is there some way how to change colour of help text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give all fonts inside the black block a white text color by using the following class;

```
.container.c1 * {
    color: #fff;
}
```

If this is the crispy form with bootstrap the following class will do the trick

```
.alert,
.alert-danger,
.alert-danger .alert-link {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Another option is to see what class the error message has in inspect element and then using that class to change the color using CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, new classes are working.